# Q points and A points, suggestion to differentiate them

Tags: feature-request, reputation, score

Shouldn't Stack Exchange differ between question points and answer points?

For example, I'm not an astronomer, but I ask lots of stupid questions about it. That gives me thousands of points. More than many here who actually are astronomers and do answer my questions. So when Ms/Mr Newuser enters and asks a question and I happen to want to answer it with my imaginations, she or he might think that I am an authority because I have thousands of points from asking similar questions. That's a system which might go wrong.

Comment: We do need questions, otherwise we can't create answers so we should reward good questions, just not as much as good answers, and we do just that because you get half the rep from upvotes to questions as you do for answers.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes of course. But a new score which shows the number of points, out of the total, that has been gained from answers would be informative. Good answers are different from good questions.

Comment: React to the answer, not the poster of the answer. Experts can be wrong occasionally and new users could be subject matter experts who've just found out about the site.

Comment: @RobertLongson But it is the poster who has the score. Of course it matters who is answering a question, especially for the questioner who doesn't know enough to make good judgement of what is a good or bad answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I ask lots of stupid questions about it. That gives me thousands of points.

No, it doesn't. Down-votes on bad questions will keep your reputation low and eventually you will be post-banned for the number of bad questions you post.

If you ask good questions, why not reward that? If you can find an interesting question that is appreciated by the community, why treat that differently than good answers?

Also, answering a question as a high-rep user doesn't say you are an expert in that subject. I can answer questions on StackOverflow regarding Android, but I have never touched the subject, although you can consider me a high-rep user.

Comment: I don't suggest stop rewarding good questions. I suggest differentiation between good questions and good answers.

Comment: That is my point: there is no use. Reputation shows your involvement in the community. Not if you are an expert on a subject. See my last paragraph.

Comment: Questioning and answering are two different roles in the community. The difference between these roles should be highlighted by the "score". Today's system with olympic medals tells me nothing, a Q vs A score would be very much more informative.

Comment: You are making the mistake you think that is related to reputation. It isn't.

Comment: Oh, so it is the users who make mistakes, not the site designers!? How convenient.

Comment: Also, answers are already differentiated from questions by contributing to a tag score and associated badges. That's enough I think to enable recognition of expert answerers in a field vs people who ask good questions.